# How can multiple parts of self be borrowed here? Isn't self borrowed mutably as well as immutably here?

Tags: rust, lifetime, self, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have this struct:

```
struct PhysicsState {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    edges: Vec<Edge>,
}
```

and I'm trying to understand why this code compiles:

```
impl PhysicsState {
    fn remove_edge(&mut self, edge_index: usize) {
        let edge = &self.edges[edge_index];    // first borrow here
        // update the edge-index collection of the nodes connected by this edge
        for i in 0..2 {
            let node_index = edge.node_indices[i];
            self.nodes[node_index].remove_edge(edge_index);   // second (mutable) borrow here ?
        }
    }
}
```

while this fails:

```
impl PhysicsState {
    pub fn edge_at(&self, edge_index: usize) -> &Edge {
        &self.edges[edge_index]
    }

    pub fn node_at_mut(&mut self, node_index: usize) -> &mut Node {
        &mut self.nodes[node_index]
    }

    fn remove_edge(&mut self, edge_index: usize) {
        let edge = self.edge_at(edge_index);    // first (immutable) borrow here
        for i in 0..2 {
                let node_index = edge.node_indices[i];
                self.node_at_mut(node_index).remove_edge(edge_index);   // second (mutable) borrow here -> ERROR
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I originally used the first version and later changed it to the second, only to see it fail.
And it makes sense to me that it fails. `self` is clearly borrowed as immutable first and then as mutable, which fails, as expected.

What I don't understand is: How does the first version work?

Clearly the first borrow (getting the `&Edge`) has to stay alive throughout the for loop, since it is used there. But how does it manage to get an additional mutable reference to a `Node` from `self` then?

The error returned by the compiler for the second version is: `` error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable ``

Why don't I get this error when using the first version?

In case you wonder:

- Node and Edge are simple structs, not implementing Copy, so that's not what's happening here
- The reason why I wanted to switch to the second version is that the two additional functions there actually contain type casts to usize, which I removed here for the sake of readability, but which I'd have to repeat everywhere in my code without these functions.

Perhaps I could instead use a macro to achieve the same effect, but over all I just wanna know how the borrowing works here, because it seems to me that I have some kind of misunderstanding about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can borrow `self.edges` and subsequently `self.nodes` in your first version, is because the compiler understands that `self.edges` and `self.nodes` are individually what's being borrowed. This is also what's called "[Splitting Borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html)" in relation to structs.

However, if you opaquely look at the method signature:

```rust
fn edge_at(&self, edge_index: usize) -> &Edge
```

Then by looking at that, do you know what's being borrowed? Not really. All you can see is that it returns `&Edge` and `&self` is being borrowed. Thereby `self` as a whole is what's being borrowed, which disallows you doing the subsequent mutable borrow of `self.nodes`, because `self` is already immutably borrowed.

---

What you essentially desire occurring, is that calling methods allow `&self` to be partially borrowed. This is not supported in Rust. However, there is an RFC dating back to 2015 requesting this feature. The RFC is titled "[Partial Borrowing (#1215)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1215)", which discusses potential syntax and semantics.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I knew that partial borrows are not supported, so I was confused how they seemed to be kind of supported in the first version, but the signature argument makes sense. I guess I'm even glad that they're not supported because this seems easy enough to work around to me and less syntax to learn is always a good thing.

If someone has a similar problem and is interested in how take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1215#issuecomment-124541853) from the mentioned RFC as well as other comments there.

Answer (score 1):

The first version works because inside a single scope the Rust borrow checker can "see" borrows at a finer granularity, so it can tell when references are being borrowed from disjoint fields of a struct, like in your example.

When you borrow from `&self.edges[edge_index]` Rust can tell the immutable reference's lifetime is specifically tied to `self.edges` and when you borrow `self.nodes[node_index].remove_edge(edge_index)` Rust can tell the mutable reference's lifetime is specifically tied to `self.nodes` and since `self.edges` and `self.nodes` are disjoint struct fields there's no overlap between the references and they can exist simultaneously.

The second example fails because you break the single scope into multiple scopes and now the Rust borrow checker can only reason about the lifetimes of the references by what you inform it via your method signatures, and the first method signature `fn edge_at(&self, edge_index: usize) -> &Edge` says that the returned reference's lifetime is tied to `&self` and the second method signature `fn node_at_mut(&mut self, node_index: usize) -> &mut Node` says that the returned reference's lifetime is tied to `&mut self` and now when you use both methods in a single scope Rust thinks you have conflicting overlapping references both borrowing from `self` (instead of non-overlapping references borrowed from `self.edges` and `self.nodes` like before) so it throws a compile error.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because the reference to splitting borrows and also the RFC was very instructive to me, but I just want you to know I had a hard time deciding, because your answer is very detailed and informative as well. Thank you.